# Can't print to wireless Epson XP-830 in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, printing, 19.10, epson

Installed a new Epson XP-830. This printer has a number of connection options, to include USB and wireless. I can't print wireless from Ubuntu 19.10.

- Windows prints to either USB or wireless connection.
- Ubuntu prints via USB connection.
- Ubuntu network discovery finds the printer properly.
- Printer added manually, or via discovery, neither prints.
- Ubuntu won't print via wireless connection.
- Epson printer drivers installed, no help.
- Will print the CUPS "Test Page" fine.
- Using Verizon MiFi hotspot for wireless.
- Computer **looks** like the print cycle is complete, although the print queue empties very quickly, and the printer indicates that it's printing for about 3 seconds, but nothing prints.

Comment: How did you install it? Using passthru, ipp, or AppSocket?

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for your question. I believe that I tried all three... however, if one of them required a hard IP address, I didn't do that, as the IP can change, and then break the printer. I tried using the "discovered" printer, or the manually "added" printer, and neither would work. I makes all of the gestures like it should be printing, but it doesn't. I think some piece of software is missing.

Comment: I suggest to use a fixed IP. You can set a fixed one in your router, or in the printer. It works much better.

Comment: @Pilot6 Problem is, we don't have our own router... this is all being done via a Verizon MiFi hotspot... and I don't think it has the capability of assigning fixed IP addresses.

Comment: I may be wrong, but my understanding is hotspots like Verizon MiFi are designed for multiple devices to connect to the internet at the same time, but not for communication between those devices. Recently there was another question about printer not working when printer and computer are connected to mobile phone WiFi hotspot.

Comment: Similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206150/printing-problem#comment2023924_1206150). If you find a solution, it may help this guy too.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for the input. I wondered about that too... but then Windows prints to it fine... so that "shouldn't" be an inter-device communication problem. And the CUPS test page prints. Very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final solution...

- set a valid static IP address in the printer (192.168.1.104)
- "Added" a printer using "AppSocket/HP JetDirect" using the above IP address

Comment: That's what I am always doing.